# QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent отказывается срабатывать

Tags: qt5

Исследую QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent, набросал вот такой код:
mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent>
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

qmyscene.h

```
#ifndef QMYSCENE_H
#define QMYSCENE_H
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QCursor>
#include <QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent>
#include <QPushButton>
class QMyScene: public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QMyScene(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~QMyScene();
private:
    void dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event);
};
#endif // QMYSCENE_H
```

qpixitem.h

```
#ifndef QPIXITEM_H
#define QPIXITEM_H
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
class QPixItem: public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    QPixItem (QGraphicsScene *MyScene,int x,int y);
    QGraphicsScene *MyScene;
    int x,y;
};
#endif // QPIXITEM_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "qmyscene.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QMyScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    //ui->graphicsView->setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

qmyscene.cpp

```
#include "qmyscene.h"
#include "qpixitem.h"
#include <qdebug.h>
#include <QMessageBox>
QMyScene::QMyScene(QObject *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent)
{
    QPixItem *pix1 = new QPixItem (this,100,100);
    QPixItem *pix2 = new QPixItem (this,50,50);
}
QMyScene::~QMyScene()
{
}
void QMyScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Scene::есть движение";
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.exec();
    //QGraphicsScene::dragMoveEvent(event);
}
```

qpixitem.cpp

```
#include "qpixitem.h"
QPixItem::QPixItem (QGraphicsScene *MyScene,int x,int y): QGraphicsPixmapItem()
{
    QPixmap  pic (":/Items/OutLet.png");
    this->setPixmap(pic);
    this->setPos(x, y);
    this->setZValue(10);
    this->setAcceptDrops(true);
    this->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    MyScene->addItem(this);
}
```

Идея проста, реализуется класс QMyScene наследуемый от QGraphicsScene в котором перегружается событие dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent)
QGraphicsPixmapItem добавлены на сцену, у них есть флаг ItemIsMovable чтобы таскать их мышкой и setAcceptDrops(true) чтобы была какая-то реакция на перетаскивание (различные темы на форуме утверждают что это важно).
Как утверждает справка dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent) срабатывает когда над сценой чего-то перетаскивают. Но вот я перетаскиваю а - void QMyScene::dragMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event) по какой-то причине не отрабатывает. Причем не важно какой код внутри, можно там делать не дебаг, а что угодно - работать не будет.
Я посмотрел пример с роботом, на сайте Qt. У меня все один в один, как в примере, но результат нулевой - отчего это происходит ?

Comment: Событие произойдет, если курсор попадет в границы сцены.  Какой у вас размер сцены и какие у нее границы?

Comment: сложный вопрос, я был уверен что сцена бесконечна, а видимая часть соответствует размерам graphicsView, который я нарисовал в редакторе форм. Это не так ?

Comment: Нет, вы можете ее задать setRect, либо она будет равна обводу элементов в нее входящих :)

Comment: то есть в любом случае, если я тащу по сцене свой QGraphicsPixmapItem событие должно вызываться, так как само помещение объектов на сцену задаёт ей какие-то границы, верно ?

Comment: Когда добавляете в сцену элемент, то сцена изменяется, если элемент выходит за границу. Если тащите внутри границ сцены, то событие должно срабатывать, но границы сцены не обязательно должны совпадать с границами GraphicsView. Ну, короче вы поняли )

Comment: Порылся в справке, нашел там метод сцены setSceneRect, похоже это он - сцена действительно увеличилась, появились полосы прокрутки, но событие не срабатывает. Добавил вот такую  строку scene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,600); в mainwindow.cpp

Comment: Попробуйте вот так https://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread1654258.html

Comment: Спасибо, я видел эту тему. Даже если прописать QGraphicsScene::dragMoveEvent(event); event->accept(); все равно не работает. Просто мистика.

Comment: А лучше вот этот пример попробовать запустить https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-dragdroprobot-example.html вот сам проект https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/graphicsview/dragdroprobot?h=5.14

Comment: Спасибо, я упоминал что смотрел этот проект. У меня же все то-же самое. Это явно какая-то мелочь, что-то сразу незаметное.